# Query document in Firestore by element inside dictionary

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document like this one located in my Firestore database:

```
{'_id': '6207IS2019', 'Meta Data': {'Ticker': 'axr', 'CIK': '6207', 'Company Name': 'AMREP CORP.', 'SIC': '2721', 'Year': '2019', 'Filing Type': 'IS'}, 'Fundamental Data': {'IncomeLossFromContinuingOper .......
```

I know that I can query the document by the _id with this query:

```
db.collection('2019').where('_id', '==', '6207IS2019').stream()
```

My question is if I can query the document by an element inside of a dictionary like "Ticker" or "CIK"

EDIT:
To solve it I used the dot notation, but it only worked if I use elements without withespaces so i had to rebuild the jsons, after that I can query this way:

MetaData.Ticker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can use dot notation to query by nested fields inside map fields:

```
db
    .collection('2019')
    .where('Meta Data.Ticker', '==', 'axr')
    .stream()
```

Comment: If yo found this answer helpful, it's customary to upvote the answer and mark it as correct using the buttons to the left.